# when asyncio.StreamReader.read() called, which type of Error occur?

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling, exception, python-asyncio

Now I make TCP server with asyncio.

I want added exception error handling in my code. (like below)

```
    try:
        data = await reader.read(SERVER_IO_BUFFER_SIZE)
    except SomeError:
        #error handle
```

So, I look asyncio official document.

but I can't find any of information about Errors that may occur.

(link: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#asyncio.StreamReader.read)

How can I get infomation about Errors that may occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact errors that may occur will depend on the type of the stream behind the `StreamReader`. An implementation that talks to a socket will raise `IOError`, while an implementation that reads data from a database might raise some database-specific errors.

If you are dealing with the network, e.g. through [`asyncio.open_connection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#asyncio.open_connection) or [`asyncio.start_server`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#asyncio.start_server), you can expect instances of `IOError` and its subclasses. In other words, use `except IOError as e`.

Also, if the coroutine is cancelled, you can get `asyncio.CancelledError` at any `await`. You probably don't want to handle that exception - just let it propagate, and be sure to use the appropriate `finally` clauses or `with` context managers to ensure cleanup. (This last part is a good idea regardless of `CancelledError`.)